# Any disadvantage to reading using a cursor in Java PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I wish to read all rows of a large table from PostgreSQL in Java. I am processing the rows one by one in the Java software.

By default the JDBC PostgreSQL driver reads all rows into memory, meaning my program runs out of memory.

The [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html) talks of "Getting results based on a cursor" using `st.setFetchSize(50);` I have implemented that and it works well.

Is there any disadvantage to this approach? If not, I would enable it for all our queries, big and small, or is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a fetchsize of `50` and you get `1000` results, it will result in `20` round-trips to the database. So no, it's not a good idea to enable it blindly without thinking of the actual queries being run.

A bigger question is why are your `ResultSets` so big that you run out of memory. Are you only loading data you're going to use and you just don't have a lot of memory, or are there perhaps poorly designed queries that return excessive results.

Comment: I don't know the postgresql protocol, but it is entirely possible that the initially buffering done when not specifying the fetchsize, could still result in _n_ roundtrips as it still has to fetch those rows (where _n_ might be smaller, but also larger the the number of roundtrips when you do specify a fetch size). The difference is that this cost is up front, as opposed to having it every 50 items while iterating.

Comment: We index an entire table of 1M entries in Lucene. So we basically do `SELECT * FROM my_table` and then process the results one by one. Only takes a few minutes, so it works well. But processing them one-by-one (or at least in batches) makes much more sense than loading them all into RAM, _then_ processing them one by one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Seems like on the wire the driver just sends `0` as the row limit if fetchsize or limit hasn't been set. I'd imagine that it would result in fetching a lot more than 50 rows at once, but I'm not going to dig into it further right now.

Comment: @AdrianSmith Certainly, but when someone asks "Is there any disadvantage to this approach? If not, I would enable it for all our queries, big and small" I can't answer with "Go right ahead! 50 is the optimal fetch size, but PostgreSQL authors just want to be d*cks".

Comment: @Kayaman Looking at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY it looks like you are right that with a single request with fetchsize 0 PostgreSQL will stream all rows.

Comment: This was a good question. I thought that the default fetch size was limited to something "normal", but apparently not.

Comment: @Mark - Just to nit-pick: The documentation says "fetch all rows". "Fetch" suggests that all rows will be sent back to the client immediately, while "stream" suggests that the rows will be sent back to the client as needed.

Comment: @GordThompson No, with streaming I mean that the server keeps on sending rows, without the client having to request more.